# How to put Task<T> into ObservableCollection and process it with EventLoopScheduler?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, observablecollection, system.reactive, observer-pattern

Currently I have a task processed by TPL scheduler:

```
var result = await task;
```

Is it possible to postpone its awaiting/execution by putting it into ObservableCollection and processing by specific Rx scheduler:

```
var scheduler = new EventLoopScheduler();

Observable
    .FromEventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
        e => _collection.CollectionChanged += e,
        e => collection.CollectionChanged -= e)
    .Where(e => e.EventArgs.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    .Select(e => e.EventArgs.NewItems.Cast<Task<T>>())
    .ObserveOn(scheduler)
    .Do(x => scheduler.Schedule(
        () => Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))) // once a second
    .Subscribe(???);
```

So calling code wouldn't be changed:

```
var result = await Later(task);
```

Comment: The code `await task;` is not "executing a task immediately"; it's (asynchronously) waiting for the task to complete. The task has already started. Are you asking how to postpone the starting of the task or the awaiting of the task?

Comment: @Stephan: yes, sure, it's awaiting, not immediate execution. Edited, thanks! My question is how to run the task not on the TPL scheduler but Rx scheduler (which will run 1 task per second)

Comment: What's your actual goal? You want to start one task per second? Or wait one second after each task finishes?

Comment: @Stephen: I want to start one task per second. Probably Observable.Sample(TimeSpan) can work here but due its super unique name I found it just now accidentally.

Comment: You want a `delegate` not a `Task`. They are very different things. A `Task` represents asynchronous computation in flight. A `delegate` is the instructions to do a computation. By the time you have a `Task` computation has already started, you can't change the behavior of where that computation gets run. Finally you should NOT need to use a collection to build a scheduler to schedule work being done on a scheduler....Just add the work onto the scheduler directly.

Comment: @Aron: yes, makes sense. I may actually want to use `Func<Task<T>>` or just `Action`. So I'll schedule running a delegate and it's  unimportant what is going on inside, if it's TPL or anything else. Do you know how should the code doing it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var do= new Do();


var result = await do.Later(() => 1 + 2);


public class Do
{
    private Subject<Action> _backlog = new Subject<Action>();

    public Do()
    {
         Observable.CombineLatest(_backlog, Observable.Timer(...), (l, r) => l)
              .Subscribe(x => x());
    }

    public Task<T> Later(Func<T> getResult)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        _backlog.OnNext(() => {
             try
             {
                 var result = getResult();
                 tcs.SetResult(result);
             }
             catch(Exception ex)
             {
                 tcs.SetException(ex);
             }
        });
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think Zip() here will add 1 second after each operation. However I want to run an operation not earlier than 1 second after previous think throttled api client). So if no operation happened or more than 1 second passed since, I want to run the operation immediately.

Comment: Also if OnNext() has return type void then how to return a result of future compilation to the caller? With `await task` it happens "automatically" for you.

Comment: btw how do you think what will work better: CombineLatest + Timer or Sample?

Comment: Really? I though Throttle will lose/drop items. And Sample won't. But it's near impossible to find example of Sample due its super unique name. Go figure... https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+rx+sample

Comment: Sample is very much like throttle, except throttle has a timeout that resets each time a next occurs. Sample does not. I have a solution using SemaphoreSlim but i am in bed at the moment. Will post tomorrow...

Comment: Appreciate! But you know, my tests show that no items are dropped by Sample but properly postponed. Sending 1 request per 500 ms and processing 1 request per 1 sec I'm getting proper ratio 1:2.

Answer (score 1):

Why use TPL at all if you plan to transition to RX? Just use something like below and use whatever scheduler you'd like.

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .Select(_ => "SomeResult")
            .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", DateTime.Now.Second, x));
```

Comment: Interval() won't work here: it's a timer. I don't need wait 1 second if there were no job before, it should run immediately. But next one should wait.

Comment: Answering why both TPL and Rx: I use TPL because access remote REST API using HttpClient, and Rx because need to schedule requests properly. API is throttled and will return 403 error.